# Como faz para quando o usuário tocar no simbolo do menu aparecer a mensagem no Toast?

Tags: android

Tenho esse método mas ele nao funciona o que faço? :(

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    MenuItem menuTeste = menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Item teste");
    menuTeste.setIcon(R.drawable.adcsimbolo);
    menuTeste.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
    return true;
}




  public boolean onMenuItemSelected (MenuItem menuItem){
    //super.onMenuItemSelected(add,menuItem);
    switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
        case 0 :
            Toast.makeText(CadastroActivity.this, "Tocado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente trocar  `onMenuItemSelected`  por `onOptionsItemSelected`!

Segue um exemplo:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case 0 :
                Toast.makeText(this, "Tocado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Se você está inflando o layout do menu, você pode adicionar o item lá no xml mesmo, não precisa ser programaticamente.

exemplo:

```
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_teste"
        android:icon="@drawable/adcsimbolo"
        android:title="Item teste"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

E pra pegar o item que foi clicado e mostrar o Toast, pegue pelo ID.

exemplo:

```
switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
   case R.id.item_teste:
       Toast.makeText(CadastroActivity.this, "Tocado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   break;
}
```